# Trying to parse a http request?

Tags: java, http, parsing

Still a bit new to programming, but with Java basically i'm trying to store the variables I get from this link. Its a testnet on a block chain and I want to manipulate the data i get from it, like store the available balance and type of network . What would be the best way to go about this? I've had experience with parsing text files but i feel like this is a bit different.

https://block.io/api/v2/get_balance/?api_key=e5ed-0847-8256-7f49

Link displays:

```
{
  "status" : "success",
  "data" : {
    "network" : "DOGETEST",
    "available_balance" : "482.00000000",
    "pending_received_balance" : "0.00000000"
  }
}
```

Comment: this structure looks like a JSON. i myself never worked with it, but there are libraries to parse them like [org.json](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java)

Comment: Try to use a JSON Parser. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json